# XML to load to tables with one attribute with multiple values

Tags: xml, oracle

Trying to load below XML to table.

Since Division has multiple values not sure how to load to table (this XML passed as parameter to procedure)

To load to MYTABLE with these columns

```
  <MYTABLE> 
        <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>3338816</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
        <DIVISIONS>
           <VALUE>1234</VALUE>
           <VALUE>1245</VALUE>
        </DIVISIONS>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>09-28-2018</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <EXPIRATION_DATE></EXPIRATION_DATE>
  </MYTABLE>

 CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
   (ACCOUNT_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(16 ), 
    DIVISIONS       VARCHAR2(20), 
    EFFECTIVE_DATE  DATE, 
    EXPIRATION_DATE DATE);
```

Comment: Added create table for xml's to load

Comment: Do you want to create one row for each division and repeat the account number?

Comment: sorry for delay ... please HOLD ON this will let you know ... thanks for asking I just checked the tables I see account number was primary key

Comment: So, how should the multiple division numbers be stored then?